# node-xmpp-server with json body messages

Tags: json, node.js, xmpp

is there any chance to get node-xmpp-server lib to handle messages body in json format ([XEP-0295](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0295.html))?

Comment: Note that XEP-0295 was submitted as an April Fools joke, in the spirit of [April Fools' Day RFCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools'_Day_Request_for_Comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize json object using stringify, send it, and then unserialize it using parse method
Lets say we have jsonObject variable:

```
var data = {'some': 'thing', 'bla': 'blah'};
var message = JSON.stringify(data);
```

and unserialize:

```
var data = JSON.parse("some serialized message");
```